# Pandas: New Column, Assign whole group based on a row

Tags: python, pandas

What is a way to add a Pandas column based on a condition "Has Covid", for the whole group "Class" in our example below? i.e. I want the "Email Alert" column, given Class, Student, and Has Covid column.

(i have searched quite a few posts but nothing seem to be applicable... i was thinking of adding a dictionary of class and do a map, but that seems inefficient)

Thanks in advance,
N

[image]

Comment: How about `df['Email Alert'] = df.groupby('Class')['Has Covid'].transform('any')` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is one way :

```
df['Email Alert'] = df.groupby('class')['hasCovid'].transform('max')
```

Comment: Thank you. I know groupby, i know transform. I am just too silly to combine the too. Thanks Eshirvana

Answer (score 1):

You can do `isin`

```
df['classCovid'] = df['class'].isin(df.loc[df['Has Covid']==1,'class']).astype(int)
```

Comment: Thank you Beny  need to learn isin and use it =D thanks again!